# How to make non optional String Optional in Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, option-type

I am implementing Stripe into my app so when I send my customer_id as a parameter in swift it needs to be optional or it doesn't work. But I pull the id from firebase as a non optional value. Is there any way I can turn the non optional id into an optional variable. code to get id from firestore:

```
docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
                                  if let document = document {
                                    id = document.get("id") as? String ?? ""
                                  }
```

id comes back as non optional. I need to send an optional variable as the id (that's the only way it works):

```
var data = ["api_version" : apiVersion, "customer_id" : id]
        
        functions.httpsCallable("getStripeEphemeralKeys").call(data)
```

THe above code gives me errors but if I send the same exact id as an optional variable it works

Comment: Any non-optional can be assigned to their optional counterpart type without any compiler complaints. Where exactly does it not work for you?

Comment: The `customer_id` seems to be your firebase function parameter which is an optional parameter. Also probably you could define your document such that the customer_id is stored as `customer_id` instead of the actual `document id` so that it could be optional

Comment: You could do `Optional.some(id)` but I doubt that is your problem

Comment: You should explain why you made `id` non-optional in the first place. Because it looks like that simply declaring it as `var id: String?` would solve your issue. Then just assign `id = document.get("id") as? String` to it, without the `?? ""` part.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Really weird how firebase returns optional if you do document["id"} as opposed to document.get("id").

```
 var id:Any? = ""
        let docRef = db.collection("Profile").document((user?.email)!)
                              docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
                                  if let document = document {
                                    id = document["id"]
                                   var data = ["api_version" : apiVersion, "customer_id" : id]
                                    self.functions.httpsCallable("getStripeEphemeralKeys").call(data) {
```